# Use the default database path to create a filegroup in a script sql server 2008

Tags: sql, sql-server-2008, sql-scripts, filegroup

Quick question, it is possible to include in a SQL Script something like this?

```
IF FILEGROUP_ID('FG') IS NOT NULL
ALTER DATABASE [MYDB]
ADD FILE (Name=[FG_DATA], Filename='{My default server path}') TO FILEGROUP [FG]
GO
```

The idea is to create a script in development that when promoted to production it can be used without changing anything.

Comment: Are you using SSDT? Or even sqlcmd to deploy?

Comment: we are running the scripts directly in Management Studio and we also create the scripts form it.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

We are using APEXSQL BUILD!! problem solved!